# Android FCM - What are the IPs and Ports for firewall?

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

Our server in a confined environment need to push notification out to devices installed with our apps. We tried our push client on an open environment and it worked. However when moved to our server, there are network error due to firewall blockage.

Based on google documents:

> If your organization has a firewall that restricts the traffic to or
> from the Internet, you need to configure it to allow connectivity with
> FCM in order for your Firebase Cloud Messaging client apps to receive
> messages. The ports to open are: 5228, 5229, and 5230. FCM typically
> only uses 5228, but it sometimes uses 5229 and 5230. FCM doesn't
> provide specific IPs, so you should allow your firewall to accept
> outgoing connections to all IP addresses contained in the IP blocks
> listed in Google's ASN of 15169.

However, we are actually pushing using the HTTP protocol with the following URL:

```
https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send
```

Does that means the port to open is now `443` instead of `5228`?

Also we will need to configure the host as well because the security team does not allow us to connect to the domain. From the paragraph above, all IP addresses is in the ASN 15169, and i had only managed to find a list [here](https://ipinfo.io/AS15169)

Anyone with experience with this can give a pointer? Thank you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Does that means the port to open is now 443 instead of 5228?

### To receive messages

You should open 5228, 5229 and 5230 as per the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#messaging-ports-and-your-firewall).

### To send messages

FCM doesn't provide specific IPs because our IP range changes too frequently and your firewall rules could get out of date impacting your users' experience.
Ideally, **you will whitelist ports 5228-5230 with no IP restrictions.**

However, if you must have an IP restriction, you should whitelist all of the IP addresses in the IPv4 and IPv6 blocks listed in [Google's ASN of 15169](https://ipinfo.io/AS15169). This is a large list and you should plan to update your rules monthly.

Comment: It is not possible to white-list any URL behind **HTTPS** as URL part is encrypted.

Comment: Which FCM IP should I whitelist for receive in a device?

Comment: @Darish could you include a link to the documentation in an answer update please?

Comment: only need to whitelist 5228 for `https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send` ? How about all ip  as mention in the document?

Comment: Based on the documentation, port 5228 is used by mobile devices to *receive* push messages, and has nothing to do with the server-side being able to *push* messages to Firebase.  This answer provides incorrect information and should not be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Darish's answer, Google does not recommend whitelisting IPs nor URLs:

> For outgoing connections, FCM doesn't provide specific IPs because our
>   IP range changes too frequently and your firewall rules could get out
>   of date impacting your users' experience. Ideally, you will whitelist
>   ports 5228-5230 with no IP restrictions. However, if you must have an
>   IP restriction, you should whitelist all of the IP addresses in the
>   IPv4 and IPv6 blocks listed in Google's ASN of 15169. This is a large
>   list and you should plan to update your rules monthly. Problems caused
>   by firewall IP restrictions are often intermittent and difficult to
>   diagnose.

You can find information about Google's IP addresses [here](https://support.google.com/a/answer/60764?hl=en) (Google help page) or [here](https://ipinfo.io/AS15169) (ipinfo.io).

You can also try these commands (from first link above, translated from `netstat` to `dig`):

```
dig @8.8.8.8 _spf.google.com TXT
dig @8.8.8.8 _netblocks.google.com TXT
dig @8.8.8.8 _netblocks2.google.com TXT
dig @8.8.8.8 _netblocks3.google.com TXT
```

The first command gets you the SPF record for Google mail servers (which is all the IPs they own). That leads you to the _netblockN.google.com TXT records which give you all the IP ranges. My queries just now yielded these results:

```
_netblocks.google.com.  3599    IN      TXT     "v=spf1 ip4:35.190.247.0/24 ip4:64.233.160.0/19 ip4:66.102.0.0/20 ip4:66.249.80.0/20 ip4:72.14.192.0/18 ip4:74.125.0.0/16 ip4:108.177.8.0/21 ip4:173.194.0.0/16 ip4:209.85.128.0/17 ip4:216.58.192.0/19 ip4:216.239.32.0/19 ~all"
_netblocks2.google.com. 3599    IN      TXT     "v=spf1 ip6:2001:4860:4000::/36 ip6:2404:6800:4000::/36 ip6:2607:f8b0:4000::/36 ip6:2800:3f0:4000::/36 ip6:2a00:1450:4000::/36 ip6:2c0f:fb50:4000::/36 ~all"
_netblocks3.google.com. 3599    IN      TXT     "v=spf1 ip4:172.217.0.0/19 ip4:172.217.32.0/20 ip4:172.217.128.0/19 ip4:172.217.160.0/20 ip4:172.217.192.0/19 ip4:172.253.56.0/21 ip4:172.253.112.0/20 ip4:108.177.96.0/19 ip4:35.191.0.0/16 ip4:130.211.0.0/22 ~all"
```

You could parse those TXT records and use the resulting IP ranges for your firewall rules. Google does recommend updating your rules monthly however.