# FCM (Firebase Cloud Messaging) : Firebase push notifications are displayed in Firefox but not in Chrome

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-chrome, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have integrated Firebase in my React code. Push Notifications are displayed in Firefox, the methods `onMessage()` and `onBackgroundMessage()` work fine in Firefox but not in Chrome.
I have initialised firebase in my App.js (Main component that loads all the components).
I have included *firebase-messaging-sw.js* in my public folder. Please let me know if I need to add/subtract anything from my code.

I have tested this code on localhost as well as on a secured domain.

Here is my
**firebase-messaging-sw.js**

```
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.2.1/firebase-app.js');
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.2.1/firebase-messaging.js');

firebase.initializeApp({
    databaseURL: 'databaseURL.firebaseio.com',
    apiKey: "apiKey",
    authDomain: "authDomain.firebaseapp.com",
    projectId: "projectId",
    storageBucket: "storageBucket",
    messagingSenderId: "messagingSenderId",
    appId: "appId"
});

const initMessaging = firebase.messaging();

initMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(function(payload) {
    console.log('[firebase-messaging-sw.js] Received background message ', payload);
    // Customize notification here
    const notificationTitle = 'Background Message Title';
    const notificationOptions = {
      body: 'Background Message body.',
      // icon: '/firebase-logo.png'
    };
  
    self.registration.showNotification(notificationTitle,
      notificationOptions);
  });
```

***App.js*** code

```
import firebase from './firebase';

export class App extends Component {

  callFirebase = () => {
    try {
      const messaging = firebase.messaging();
      messaging.requestPermission().then(() => {
        return messaging.getToken({ vapidKey: "vapidKey" })
      })
        .then((token) => {
          console.log("Connected To FIREBASE")
          console.log("Token: ", token);
          this.props.firebaseToken(token);
        })
        .catch(e => {
          this.props.firebaseToken(null);
          console.log("Err from firebase", e)
        })

      messaging.onMessage(function (payload) {
        console.log("Message received. ", payload);
        // ...
      });
    }
    catch (e) {
      console.log("Error from firebase: ", e);
    }

  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.callFirebase();
  }

render() {
    return (
     <Code/>
    );
  }
}


export default (App);
```

Answer (score 1):

It can be a Firewall configuration issue, You can try with different internet and if it works then you need to add this configuration to the firewall.

**To Receive Notification:**

You need open 5228, 5229 and 5230 as per the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options).

Original Answer: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45529055/7488168)

Comment: The OP is referring to browsers (Firefox, Chrome) and your answer relates to Android native apps, correct?

Comment: No, my answer is for Chrome and Firefox browser related only