# firebase fcm background notifications are not working on chrome and working perfectly fine on firefox

Tags: google-chrome, firebase-cloud-messaging

Here is the code of my service worker file "firebase-messaging-sw.js"

[firebase-messaging.sw.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NY2mU.png)

and same version I am using to get token.

Sharing what I have already tried,
tested with many other projects online by replacing my project configurations only none of them worked for chrome as earlier when we implemented this feature it was tested and working 100% fine for the chrome browser but now it's not.

> I created from scratch one in react using latest firebase sdk version 10.7.1 and tried sending notification from the firebase test message console section

> cloned a project from this repo and added my credentials it worked fine for firefox for both foreground and background messages
> https://github.com/AudreyHal/React-Firebase-Cloud-Messaging-Demo

> and then downloaded this code from the official google firebase repo in the messaging folder and then used the same version of firebase for service worker and normal messages but issue was still same, working on firefox but not on chrome
> https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-js/blob/master/messaging/README.md

> and I thought it may be because of the chrome's latest update so I uninstalled my current browser and install the version which was launched in June 2022, but issue stood same

by doing these and after chat with GPT

I was only able to find somewhat the issue but not solution yet

> I was only getting and still getting same error which is "uncaught (in promise) undefined"
> this error is thrown by the promise rejection by this method self.registration.showNotification() this method if called from inside the service worker or when called just after registering the service worker from outside the service worker where we set the path to register it, it gives the same error. by checking online people were saying issue could be one of these

1. invalid icon path (tested but not resolved the issue)
2. lack of permissions to show notification but is not the case as I called this method after getting permissions from the user in the browser

- tried to put it in the try catch block
- and showNotification().then().catch() block but error had nothing as this showNotification promise resolves to undefined so nothing gets caught and found nothing in catch block other than undefined.

> and I have made sure that service worker was installed and activated and checked it's state inside the service worker and outside the service worker. and did everything what people are doing as everyone is saying the same method to receive background notifications so tried all of them and tried using older non modular sdk and new modular sdk versions of firebase with importscripts tried using simple libraries and compat ones as documentation suggests.

but none of the above solved the issue.

expected results : It should be working fine on chrome too as it used to be.

Answer (score 0):

Try opening ports 5228-5230 and 443.

You may also need to allow these hostnames:

```
mtalk.google.com
mtalk4.google.com
mtalk-staging.google.com
mtalk-dev.google.com
alt1-mtalk.google.com
alt2-mtalk.google.com
alt3-mtalk.google.com
alt4-mtalk.google.com
alt5-mtalk.google.com
alt6-mtalk.google.com
alt7-mtalk.google.com
alt8-mtalk.google.com
android.apis.google.com
device-provisioning.googleapis.com
firebaseinstallations.googleapis.com
```

Sources: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#messaging-ports-and-your-firewall

[FCM (Firebase Cloud Messaging) : Firebase push notifications are displayed in Firefox but not in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66022165/fcm-firebase-cloud-messaging-firebase-push-notifications-are-displayed-in-fi?rq=2)